# How to use GPU in tf contrib estimator

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I have a machine with 4 gpus on cloud ml. how can I make my tf contrib estimator make use of GPUs on the machine? can I make the estimator make use of all of them?

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of estimators: "[pre-made](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/estimators#pre-made_estimators)" and "[custom](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/estimators#custom_estimators)".

None of the pre-made estimators (e.g. [DNNClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNClassifier)), currently work with multiple GPUs -- all of the computation will happen on a single GPU.

**UPDATE 2018/07/18*** (based on tombstone's post): [DistributionStrategy](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/README.md) simplifies creating "custom" estimators that run on multiple GPUs.

"Custom" estimators are estimators you write. They can therefore do anything you would like, including leveraging multiple GPUs. In this case, you simply need to be sure to write your `model_fn` with the appropriate `tf.device` statements to assign ops to the right GPUs (TensorFlow [requires](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu#using_a_single_gpu_on_a_multi-gpu_system) you to manually assign ops when you have multiple GPUs). This usually involves the use of [towers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu#using_multiple_gpus), which just means repeating the model structure on each GPU. From the TensorFlow [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu#using_multiple_gpus):

```
# Creates a graph.
c = []
for d in ['/gpu:2', '/gpu:3']:
  with tf.device(d):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3])
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2])
    c.append(tf.matmul(a, b))
```

The above often works well, but if you want to further optimize performance, see this [advanced guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_models).

The [CIFAR-10 sample](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/cifar10_estimator) demonstrates the use of multiple GPUs in an estimator for image classification.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!

Comment: is it still the case that no pre-made estimators work with multiple GPUs? TF Object Detection just switched from TF slim based to estimator based training and I can no longer get multi-gpu to work.

Comment: Ability to use multiple GPUs will depend on the implementation of each pre-made estimator. I'd be very surprised of Object detection did not support multiple GPUs. I'll try to find someone that can help.

Comment: @Austin Tensorflow Object Detection API does not support single worker multi-gpu training via the new tf.Estimator based binaries (model_main.py). If you were using old binaries {train,eval}.py for multi-gpu training you can still access them from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/legacy . We are evaluating moving to tf.keras or tf.layers for model construction which will make it easy to support all estimator distribution strategies listed here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/README.md

Comment: @tombstone hmm going from supporting multi GPU to not supporting it seems like a big step backwards, no?

Comment: @Austin, yes we understand and that is why we still maintain the old binaries under the `legacy` directory to support this use case. I can add some documentation clarifying this.

Comment: @tombstone okay thanks I will continue to use the old binaries. Does there happen to be any information I can read about behind the development decisions that details why this update was released without support for this common use case?

Comment: We did attempt support single worker multi-gpu training with the new binaries. Unfortunately, we hit some road bumps that needed more time and work. As a result we are evaluating using to tf.keras/tf.layers for model construction which should make it a lot easier to support distribution strategies with tf estimators.